# Android test application on a real device

Tags: android, sdk, emulation

I'm trying to test a test app I developed on android 2.2 sdk on my htc phone with Froyo on it (2.2).
In the emulator it works fine, when I export as unsigned app and try to install on the phone, it doesn't allow me, just telling me 'application non installed'.
The phone has the settings to accept installation of non android application, so I'm not sure why I can't test on it.
Is it because it's not signed?

Any idea?

Thx fellas

Comment: You can't tell your phone to accept unsigned apps. Sign it, even with a debug key. What's the output when you call `adb install` manually?

Comment: yeah I finally tried to sign it (thought it took longer to do), it works just fine now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mistaking "run non-market apps" with "run unsigned apps". Android apps need to be signed, unless you have a very vile ROM that circumvents this check.

Sign the app, or run it through Eclipse (which auto-signs it with a debug key).

Answer (score 0):

Run in from Eclipse, it will install just fine.